# sending ticket reservation on mail

Tags: php, laravel

i need to send an email to the user after saving a ticket any leads how i can do that?
This is my store function

```php
     // Create Ticket

      $ticket=new Ticket;
      $ticket->userName= $request->input('userName');
      $ticket->userEmail= $request->input('userEmail');
      $ticket->phoneNumber= $request->input('phoneNumber');
      $ticket->regular_quantity= $request->input('regular_quantity');
      $ticket->vip_quantity= $request->input('vip_quantity');
      $ticket->event_id=$request->route('id');
      $ticket->total= $request->input('regular_quantity') + $request->input('vip_quantity');


      $event = Event::find($ticket->event_id);
      if ($ticket->regular_quantity < $event->regular_attendies && $ticket->vip_quantity < $event->vip_attendies) {
          if($event->regular_attendies>0 && $event->vip_attendies>0){
        DB::table('events')->decrement('regular_attendies', $ticket->regular_quantity);
        DB::table('events')->decrement('vip_attendies', $ticket->vip_quantity);

         Mail::send('emails.booking-enquiry', compact('request', 'user', 'data'), function($message) use ($request, $user, $data){
        $message->from('matildamariwa3@@gmail.com');
        $message->to($ticket->email);
        $message->subject('Booking Enquiry');
    });

        $ticket->save();

    }
    }


       else{
          echo"no available space";
       } 
       return redirect('/');
    }
```

After booking i need to send email for confirmation

Comment: So what is the problem here? You can simply do, if($ticket->save()) { // send email }

Answer (score 0):

if you use ->create() instead of ->save() you will get an instance of the ticket model you just created. Then you can just write another mail after $ticket->create();

Answer (score 0):

First `$ticket->save();` should be before you dispatch mail. Then only you should send mail to the user. In case, if save, failed, the user gets mail that user booking success. But on the other hand, DB doesn't have a record of it.

The best way to send mail is by creating [Event Listener](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events). You can find [this example which I found best among all the sites](https://medium.com/@rafaelogic/send-email-using-laravel-5-7-events-listeners-c1da03560c8f)

Simply dispatch `event(new EventClass($event));` so rest will be handled on Listener and it goes as normal.